# Referring to an unknown string from a different worksheet

Tags: string, excel, reference

Sheet1 has 2 columns "Product" and "Price". Sheet2 has data in the form "Object.Price" ex. TV.500

I need to refer to the data on Sheet2 and produce it on Sheet1 into its related column. So for TV.500, in Sheet1 it should show TV in the "Product" column and 500 in the "Price" column.

This is what I have so far

```
With Worksheets("Report").Range("A2")
    .Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")
End With
```

This give me the entire data. How do I split it up? This needs to work for all combinations of objects and prices which are unknown to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Report").Range("A2")
    .resize(1, 2) = split(Worksheets("Data").Range("A1"), chr(46))
End With
```

I
ve added a call to the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) so both values are written as once.

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively new to VBA so sorry if this is a really simple question.